# match only if this is included regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a regular expression to match s piece of text with anything in e.g

`56364657andletters witespace and )(*&-^`

I want it to only match the group IF it contains [test]
anywhere in the string e.g

`random stri[test]ng == True`
or
`ran[test]dom stri[test]ng == True`

at the moment i'm using python 2.7 if that helps

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I want it to test against (.)* or something of that nature so something like: if it contains [test] then match (.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`in`](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details)

```
input = "ran[test]dom stri[test]ng"
if "[test]" in input: 
    print "found"
```

See [running version](http://ideone.com/CjQkhf)